# Hidden elements reappears when another function is called

Tags: javascript

I made a to-do app and I made three radio buttons to give the option for user to view all tasks, completed tasks and uncompleted tasks. When I switch between them, they work as planned. I created a function and used `display: none` and `display: ""` to hide and show elements.

The problem is when I change the task to/from completed, all the hidden element reappear again.

Example: In the first pic I was in the complete view and I clicked on '2' to mark it as incomplete. In the second pic the other hidden elements appeared again.

[image]
[image]

Why are they reappearing again? I tried calling the function again inside the `completeList()` function but nothing happened.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jho25m4p/ (the functions are in line 66 & 103).

Here are the two functions:

````
function radioButtons(e){
  const taskLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  const el = e.target;
    if(el.checked && el.value == "value1"){
      taskLi.forEach(li => {
        if(li.classList.contains('done') || !li.classList.contains('done')) {
        li.style.display = "";
        }
      })

    }
    else if(el.checked && el.value == "value2") {
      taskLi.forEach(li => {
       if(li.classList.contains('done')){
         li.style.display = "";
       }
       else if (!li.classList.contains('done')){
         li.style.display = "none";
       }

    })
    }
    else if(el.checked && el.value == "value3") {
      taskLi.forEach(li => {
       if(li.classList.contains('done')){
          li.style.display = "none";
       }
       else if(!li.classList.contains('done')){
        li.style.display = "";
       }
     })

    }
}


// mark as complete
function completeList(e) {

  const targetLi = e.target.tagName === 'LI' ? e.target : e.target.parentElement;
  const lisArr = Array.from(list.children);
  const index = lisArr.indexOf(targetLi);
  const taskLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');

  taskLi.forEach(li => {

    if(li.contains(e.target)){
      li.classList.toggle('done');
      items[index].done = !items[index].done;
      populateList(items, list);
      localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
    }

  });

};```
````

Comment: `const taskLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');` This is all the LI in the document, not just the current task.

Comment: `if(li.classList.contains('done') || !li.classList.contains('done'))` so, basically always run the code? :)

Comment: @Barmar I know. I don't have 'Li' other than the ones I want so I just used it. Is it related to my problem or another problem?

Comment: The code is very confusing `list.addEventListener('click', deleteTask);
list.addEventListener('click', completeList);` Clicking on the same element deletes the task and also marks it as completed?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I wanted all elements to be showing so that's what I came up with. And this will only run if the 'All' is checked.

Comment: @Mohammed Get rid of the `if` in that section, and just set `li.style.display = ""` unconditionally.

Comment: PS. accessibility-wise - don't use `<span>` as a button. Use... guess what! `<button type="button">`

Comment: @Barmar Regarding your second reply. I could be wrong but it wont delete or mark it as complete unless the if statement condition is met. so I guess there's no problem, right?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue... but the JS is unnecessarily big....

Comment: I also can't reproduce the problem. I added 2 tasks, then clicked on Task 2, it turned green. Then I clicked on Complete, it only showed Task 2. I clicked on Incomplete, it only showed Task 1.

Comment: The if condition is not necessary if you want it to match everything.

Comment: @Barmar If you're in the 'incomplete' and you click on Task 1 to mark it as complete, it will show the other green task even though you didn't change to view 'complete'. I hope my point was clear.

Comment: You call `populateList()` in `completeTask()`. This rewrites all the HTML for the task list, and doesn't hide the tasks that don't match the current criteria in the radio buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`completeTask()` calls `populateList()`, which rewrites the HTML for the task list, so all the tasks become visible.

This isn't necessary, get rid of it.